# how to traceroute tor proxy and see other routers in tor network?

Tags: tor, traceroute

I want to know where send my packets when I connect to tor network.I want to see other routers in tor network something like this :

```
$ traceroute google.com
 3  ...........
 4  *  *  *
 5  10.201.42.148 (10.201.42.148)  54.956 ms  56.407 ms  59.104 ms
 6  10.201.22.102 (10.201.22.102)  61.025 ms  31.367 ms  34.039 ms
 7  10.201.42.98 (10.201.42.98)  32.429 ms  34.116 ms  38.702 ms
 8  so-9-0-0-xcr2.fra.cw.net (62.208.212.145)  150.821 ms  151.962 ms  156.098 ms
 9  ae0-xcr1.fra.cw.net (195.2.30.25)  158.298 ms  160.738 ms  164.934 ms
 10  xe-0-0-1-xcr1.fix.cw.net (195.2.28.202)  165.350 ms 195.2.9.238 (195.2.9.238)        167.547 ms xe-0-0-1-xcr1.fix.cw.net (195.2.28.202)  170.478 ms
 11  72.14.198.109 (72.14.198.109)  257.707 ms
```

but I want that travel of the packet among anonymous routers in tor network.how can I use `traceroute` command or other commands to find the travel of packet in tor network ? is it possible? and finally sorry for my bad english .

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like this can be done(not for 50 bounty anyways!), according to the [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en) site:

> Tor helps to reduce the risks of both simple and sophisticated traffic
>   analysis by distributing your transactions over several places on the
>   Internet, so no single point can link you to your destination. The
>   idea is similar to using a twisty, hard-to-follow route in order to
>   throw off somebody who is tailing you — and then periodically erasing
>   your footprints. Instead of taking a direct route from source to
>   destination, data packets on the Tor network take a random pathway
>   through several relays that cover your tracks so no observer at any
>   single point can tell where the data came from or where it's going.
>
> To create a private network pathway with Tor, the user's software or
>   client incrementally builds a circuit of encrypted connections through
>   relays on the network. The circuit is extended one hop at a time, and
>   each relay along the way knows only which relay gave it data and which
>   relay it is giving data to. No individual relay ever knows the
>   complete path that a data packet has taken. The client negotiates a
>   separate set of encryption keys for each hop along the circuit to
>   ensure that each hop can't trace these connections as they pass
>   through.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

You cannot see where the packet is going after the first tor node.

Answer (score 0):

Tor Browser is able to display [the circuit](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/managing-identities/). I'm very confused about how that's possible though and would love to know.

[relay path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rmV5.png)